# Workmanager not working when app is in background

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-workmanager

I'm trying to periodically run a service even when the app is killed or is in the background using workManager.

My RequestService class is given below:-

```
public class RequestService extends Worker {

public RequestService(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    displayNotification("MY Worker", "Background work Started");
    Log.i("BackJob","Running");
    return Result.SUCCESS;
}

private void displayNotification(String title, String task){

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("MyApp","My Notifications",
                                                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "My Notifications").
                                                    setContentTitle(title).setContentText(task)
                                                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    notificationManager.notify(130, notification.build());

}}
```

This is the main activity code:-

```
        final PeriodicWorkRequest WorkReq = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(RequestService.class,15,TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(WorkReq);
```

The issue is if the app is killed or is in the background then workmanager stops working.
I'm testing this on a samsung device with android version pie.

P.S :- if the app is open then i see notifications continuously after 15 mins....however as soon as i close the app.....it stops working.....and there are no more notifications

Comment: Can you take a look at the WorkManager codelab source? it implements some Worker classes showing notification. It includes a `makeStatusNotification` that solves the same problem: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager/blob/ec9e065086ce5912f3a3ae7cbd039ea6da086531/app/src/main/java/com/example/background/workers/WorkerUtils.java#L60

Comment: Did you get the solution? I'm facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

As Per the PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder official documentation available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS)

The intervalMillis must be greater than or equal to PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS

This value is currently set to 900000 ms i.e, 15 minutes.

Comment: Refer to the post....that is what I'm using....15 minutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES

Comment: Ok, have you tested on other devices. Samsung devices have some testing issues.

Comment: Yes, still no success

Answer (score 2):

You can use foreground Service for this , Foreground Service work when app is in background.

add this method in downork method

```
setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(progress));
```

Override this method in `workermanager` class

```
 @NonNull
    private ForegroundInfo createForegroundInfo(@NonNull String progress) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel("1", "channelName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        }

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1")
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setTicker("title")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();

        return new ForegroundInfo(1,notification);
    }
```

Now you app will work in the background.

Comment: Anyone tried this solution? - Specially on Android 9 & 10? -

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example that currently shows any notification regarding the version of the SO. But seemingly the problem can be related with the *notify* method from *NotificationManagerCompat*

```
private void makeStatusNotification(String message, Context context) {

    String channelId = context.getString(R.string.worker_sync_notif_channel_id);

    // Make a channel if necessary
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+
        CharSequence name = context.getString(R.string.worker_sync_notif_channel_name);
        String description = context.getString(R.string.worker_sync_notif_channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Add the channel
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    // Create the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_upload)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.worker_sync_notif_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.worker_sync_notif_subject))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(message))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(new long[0])
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    // Show the notification
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late rply.....thank you for the ans....and I'm able to show the notifications but but still when the app is in the background workmanager stops periodic requests